# Postgresql character varying strange behaviour

Tags: postgresql, character-encoding, varchar

I have a table in which `client_code` is a `character varying(10)` column.

Now, this query does not work :

```
insert into mydb.mytable (CLIENT_CODE) values ('0123456789');
```

I get `ERROR: value too long for type character varying(10)`.

When putting 9 characters in the query, it runs fine.

It seems strange to me. It's not [the definition of character varying](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) i've read.

I use PostgreSQL 9.3.19 with `ENCODING = 'UTF8'` and `LC_CTYPE = 'French_France.1252'`.

Comment: Can you post the output of `select * from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'client_code';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below row 1 is copypasted your string and row two is intered manually by me:

```
t=# with d(s,t) as (values(1,'0123456789'),(2,'0123456789'))
select *,char_length(t),ascii(t),ascii(substring(t,2,1)) from d;
 s |     t      | char_length | ascii | ascii
---+------------+-------------+-------+-------
 1 | 0123456789 |          11 | 65279 |    48
 2 | 0123456789 |          10 |    48 |    49
(2 rows)
```

you have http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` as fisrt char - you dont see it, but postgres does